# Add a new column in Doctrine 2 in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have Zend framework script with doctrine 2.

I need to add a new column, what is the correct chronology to go about doing that i.e create column, update entities, run migration etc.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want manually  then  create a  column in database table  and   specify that column  in you entity class
 as  bellow

```
/**
  * @ORM\Column(type="string") // if column is varchar 
  */
 protected $title;
```

if you have already set a CLI  for generate entity and database schema file Then use this

-- add  New variable ie column name in  Entity class

```
  /**
  * @ORM\Column(type="string") // if column is Varchar 
  */
  protected $title;
```

and execute this command

> doctrine  orm:schema-tool:update --force  update

for more detail about CLI use this link 
 http://wildlyinaccurate.com/useful-doctrine-2-console-commands