# Add new table or column on Zend Framework 1.11

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I'm currently given a running website, which using Zend-Framework 1.11 (to be precise, 1.11.11) with Doctrine 2.3 on it.

[I know, it's a very-very OLD version, but unfortunately, I can't upgrade it to newer version, since I'm really afraid that it will causing more trouble and destroy this website entirely lol!!]

I'm new with this ZF, but having a bit experience with other framework, such as - Laravel and CodeIgniter.

So, my question is -

1. **How can I add a new table (or column)** to an existing database (or table) **using ZF-way or CLI-way**?

   For example - I'm having a Table called **Supplier**, with 4 columns

   - id
   - name
   - contact
   - phone

   I want to add **mobile_phone**, a new column. How can I do that?

---

2. I need to add a new Table, exactly the same like **Supplier** above, how can I do that?

   I experienced before, to add 2 new tables, BUT I did that manually... and it's such a pain.

   Because, I need to create a file, edit the existing Model file (to create a relationships/FK) and then edit the Model **Entity**, and surprisingly, when I try to create its functionality, like Insert/Update/Delete, it shows me an error, that I need to create a Model **Proxy** too, which I check, it suppose be auto-generated.

---

3. Is there any good way to add that table (or column)? maybe using CLI or else?

---

4. Is there a way, to check, IF I can use doctrine-CLI? maybe something like `doctrine --v`? or something like that

   I did try `php doctrine list` on project root folder and it fails - `Could not open input file: doctrine`.

---

I found those questions (maybe) same like here - [Add a new column in Doctrine 2 in Zend Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18568046/4162090).

But, to be honest, I really don't know how it works **and** is that can be executed on **project root folder**?

I did try check on the [details link about doctrine CLI](https://wildlyinaccurate.com/useful-doctrine-2-console-commands/) that provided there, but still, I don't understand how to set it up.

On that link too, it drives me to [this link](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.4/reference/tools.html), about how to set-up doctrine CLI, but, as I state, I kind of confuse, how I add / create the file.

---

> In summary, I want to know, is there any way, to create a new Table? Like, on Laravel, we can create a new Table using their `artisan:make`?
>
> And, is there a better way, to add new a Column on the existing Table?
>
> FYI - I can do this syntax on my **project root folder** `zf show version.?`, IF, I can use **zf** syntax to create table and adding new column, I'm okay with that too. :)

Thanks in advance & Cheers! :)

`I'm really sorry, if this thread/question is too long or not a straight-forward question, as I'm getting frustrated, to find a good documentation about this old ZF version`

Comment: Check this - https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/ru/zend.tool.usage.cli.html

Comment: thanks for the reference @Dmitry! It's helpful for me as my starting point to research around!